# Passing variables to React Native Webview?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-webview

I am trying to pass some variable data to my Webview when it first loads using react-native-webview. However, it doesn't seem to be working the way I am doing it using template literals.

```
const arr = ["something"]

const injectedJS = `let webviewArr = ${arr}`

return (
<WebView
        scalesPageToFit={false}
        mixedContentMode="compatibility"
        injectedJavaScript={injectedJS}
        src={{ html: `some html here` }}
  />
)
```

Why doesn't this work? It works fine if I just use hard-coded data. But when I need to import the data from somewhere else and implant it into my Webview, this method just breaks the app.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that double stringifying (I don't know how else to word it) works okay.

```
let arr = ['"something"']
```

or

```
let str = "something"
const injectedJS = `let webviewArr = ['${str}']`
```

Let me know if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
const arr = JSON.stringify(["something"]);
const injectedJS = `let webviewArr = ${arr}`;
```